# design review, extra selects to gain abstraction in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I hope that stackoverflow is the correct place to ask this, I feel a bit on the fence but didn't find that it really fit better into another stack-exchange site.

So, the question is pretty much about "best-practice" or design in mysql, I don't see this done a lot in tutorials and resources why I am a bit afraid that it is not a good way to do it, so I thought I'd try to get some feedback.

I tried to make a layout as an example (thanks for commenting)
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rBRUhX3DYiTgGyBPSgQfCm/2

I have a layout similar to this:

```
table: player
+----+------+------+
| id | name | data |
+----+------+------+
|  1 | foo  | bar  |
|  2 | test | test |
+----+------+------+
```

Then I have tables to pick specific information

```
table: user_external_name
+----+----------+
| id | nickname |
+----+----------+
|  1 | baz      |
|  2 | qux      |
+----+----------+
```

And I have a third table containing matches between players, something like:

```
table: matches
+---------+--------+--------+
| matchid | homeid | awayid |
+---------+--------+--------+
|    0    |    1   |    2   |
+---------+--------+--------+
```

And then I might do queries like this on matches:

```
SELECT 
    (SELECT nickname from user_external_name WHERE id = matches.home) as home,
    (SELECT nickname from user_external_name WHERE id = matches.away) as away
FROM matches;
```

I also realized that I can make use of joins to make the query and that way I go get rid of the multiple selects. I am still not sure why the design is dumb, but I figured out that what I need to read about is pretty much relational databases. I will leave my original above for reference if someone else come stumbling down this road.

```
SELECT
    h.nickname home,
    a.nickname away
FROM `matches` as m
join user_external_name as h on h.id = m.home
join user_external_name as a on a.id = m.away;
```

resulting in:

```
+------+------+
| home | away |
+------+------+
| baz  | qux  |
+------+------+
```

**So the actual question**
Is this a reasonable way of doing it, or is it dumb in some way? One of my main arguments are that this way I can reuse the id to get the specific information by id in other tables (i.e. I never have to copy the actual name). Could you point me to a better way of doing this, or some resources/suggestions as how to think in this situation?

Thanks for taking the time to read through and hopefully I can learn something good. :)

Comment: It's a dumb way. It's also wrong.

Comment: That gives me some information at least, would you care to elaborate as I can't seem to figure out a less dumb way :)

Comment: No, not a present. This answers the question. If you want a more thorough explanation, consider revising your question - and see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query). Note that, while 'minimal', a data set comprising just one row is rarely 'complete'.

Comment: Thank you, that's very good information! I put some time trying to make an example. Very good link, I will try to update to give the information specified in it.

Comment: In my experience there are no dumb questions. People who don't ask, end up making big time mistakes. SQL is a declarative language, not an imperative one. Now, the first option is pretty much an imperative way of telling the db engine what to do; nothing wrong with it but you are assuming the engine needs to read `matches` first, and then the other tables. On the flip side, using `JOIN` gives the engine an opportunity to assess the tables and decide for itself; the query planner and the query optimizer will evaluate multiple plans and will pick the best one. Let the engine optimize for you.

Comment: "Is this a reasonable way of doing it, or is it dumb in some way?" Before editing, "this" referred to your 1st way, but now it seems to refer to your 2nd way. PS This is a faq & not researched. Search via google with 'site:'. Research query optimization/impliementation in the relational model, SQL & MySQL. PS Put everything necessary for your question in your post as text, not just at a fiddle. Use helpfully meaningful names & values. [help]

Comment: Your situation is rather simple; the choice is mostly a coin flip.  In some _other_ situations, performance of one approach can be significantly better than the other.  And I mean _either_ approach may be better.  I applaud you for understanding that there are at least two ways to the query.